# Python char encoding

Tags: python, encoding, smtplib

I have the following code :

```
msgtxt = "é"

msg = MIMEText(msgtxt)
msg.set_charset('ISO-8859-1')
msg['Subject'] = "subject"
msg['From'] = "from@mail.com"
msg['To'] = "to@mail.com"
serv.sendmail("from@mail.com","to@mail.com", msg.as_string())
```

The e-mail arrive with Ã© as its body instead of the expected é

I have tried :

```
msgtxt = "é".encode("ISO-8859-1")
msgtxt = u"é"
msgtxt = unicode("é", "ISO-8859-1")
```

all yield the same result.

How to make this work?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance, J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msgtxt = "é"
msg.set_charset('ISO-8859-1')
```

Well, what's the encoding of the source file containing this code? If it's UTF-8, which is a good default choice, just writing the `é` will have given you the two-byte string `'\xc3\xa9'`, which, when viewed as ISO-8859-1, looks like `Ã©`.

If you want to use non-ASCII byte string literals in your source file without having to worry about what encoding the text editor is saving it as, use a string literal escape:

```
msgtxt = '\xE9'
```

Comment: That was not exactly the problem but i was in fact overlooking the source file encoding, its working now, thank you for the input.J

Answer (score 0):

```
# coding: utf-8        (or whatever you want to save your source file in)
msgtxt = u"é"
msg = MIMEText(msgtxt,_charset='ISO-8859-1')
```

Without the `u` the text will be in the source encoding.  As a Unicode string, msgtxt will be encoded in the indicated character set.